# My Passport Ultra transfer speed

Tags: mac, external-disk, performance, data-transfer

I bought this device to replace an older HP external drive.  This WD drive comes with a USB 3C cable and a USB 3 adapter.  Im using it on a MPB -  USB3 port.  WD will only give me "theoretical" speed and not practical speed or expected speed.  Can anyone comment on what I might expect?  I seem to only be getting 46 to 61 MBps transfer speed which is slower than the 7 year old drive its replacing.  Trying to figure out why.  Tks for any help!!

[image: WDinfo]

[image: Apple info1]
[image: USB info]
[image: WD Info updated]

Comment: There is a free app on the app store named Black Magic Disk Speed Test which will determine the read and write speed of the selected drive.  It was originally developed to determine video capability but still gives you actual read and write speeds.

Comment: Get Info on the disk and tell us what *Format* the drive has: i.e. Mac OS Extended (Journaled), ExFAT, etc. I also don't see the disk in the list of USB devices you've presented, just the keyboard/trackpad, the card-reader, and the BT transceiver.

Comment: What's a USB3 adapter?  Also, in the USB report, I'm not seeing the WD drive where it's attached.  Can you provide the info from the system report showing the WD?

Comment: Sorry - I don’t show the report with the drive attached as I just did the report to show the MBP has a USB3. A new report is above. Also, USB3 adapter plug comes with the WD drive and converts the USBC

Comment: Sorry, didn’t include the drive report while drive attached. Just did the report to show the MBP is USB3. A new report is above. The WD is formatted OS Extended (journaled).   USB3 adapter plug comes with WD drive and adapts the supplies USB3c plug to USB.   Tks!

Comment: jmf - I know the speed. What I’m trying to asserrain is if if what I’m experiencing is what’s expected for a usb 3 speed seeing as HD only gives theoretical speeds.  Tks much.